# How do I fight the CEO of Square Enix in 3C3C1D119440927?

Tags: nier-automata

In the promotional material and surrounding articles for the 3C3C1D119440927 DLC, I saw a few things mention that I'd be able to fight the CEO of Square Enix as a boss.

However, having beaten all of the arena trials, I still don't know how to challenge him. Unlike the arenas, I was not given a quest marker for this. Where do I need to go/who do I need to talk to in order to fight Yosuke Matsuda?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer, he isn't the only boss in the DLC, though. I was specifically talking about the CEO of Square Enix who literally makes an appearance in the game.

Comment: Feel free to change it to "final boss", "secret boss", "extra boss" or anything that suits him. As long as it's not clickbait

Comment: Basically, drop the "pick a fight"

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer apologies for the last edit. We made them at the same time. I'll remove pick a fight if that will make it better

Comment: No problem, I just have a personal dislike about such titles. If you really believe your title was appropriate and don't want to give it up, I can't stop you from changing it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to fight Yosuke Matsuda, you need to talk to a relatively inconspicuous Resistance member in the third arena (the one in the Flooded City). It's worth noting that, in order to find her, you will need to have completed through the rank S challenge at this colosseum (that is, you need to have beaten that challenge, not just unlocked it).

Inside the actual arena, to the left of the entrance and at the top of the stands, is the "Resistance Secretary."

[image: resistance secretary]

Talking to her will prompt her to ask you if she can help with anything. You will need to select the "I want to fight you-know-who" option 3 separate times for her to decide to allow you to fight him.

[image: you-know-who]

After this, she will ask one last time, saying that the fight will break the immersion. If you choose "Immersion schmimmersion!" you'll fight Yosuke Matsuda.

[image: immersion schimmersion]

Comment: I just cannot find that secretary after finishing ABCDE endings, why?

Comment: @kuanyui you don't have to have gotten the endings, you just need the DLC, as far as I know. Do you have the DLC and are you in the correct colosseum?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. If no DLC installed I should not find the Colosseum at all.

Comment: @kuanyui I'm not sure if it's required or not, but have you beaten the colosseum challenges already? Are you sure you're looking in the right spot?

Comment: Yes, Flood city and I have beaten to A

Comment: @kuanyui does that mean you've cleared A or you have unlocked A? Try beating S and then check again. Recommended level for the CEOs appears to be around 85, so if you can't beat the rank S trial, there's not really a point in challenging the CEOs anyways. I can't check if you have to beat all the available trials first since I'd already beaten through rank S when I challenged the CEOs, but if that is the case, please let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: A cleared, S is unlocked but hasn't beaten.

Comment: @kuanyui try beating S and then seeing if you can find the android, I have a feeling that might be required, though I haven't seen it mentioned explicitly anywhere...

Comment: Yes, you are right. After finishing S, I indeed find the secretary and make an appointment to meet CEO. XD

Comment: @kuanyui perfect, thank you so much! I'll edit my answer with this information for others to see.